# Dragged item disappears on drop

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

I have a draggable picture and 2 divs as a drop target. You are supposed to drag the item back and forth between those 2 divs.
I also have a text inside the divs which I want to disappear when item dropped on it (and possibly appear again when dragged from.)

I'm using this and it makes the text disappear but the thing is that the photo disappears as well and cannot be dragged again.

Can someone see where the problem could be?
Thanks

```js
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    if (ev.target.id == 0) {
        document.getElementById('0').textContent = '';
    } else if (ev.target.id == 1){
        document.getElementById('1').textContent = '';
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="inbl photo"><img src="pic.jpg" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1"></img></div>
<div id="0" class="dragdiv1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">Drag&Drop Area</div>
<div id="1" class="dragdiv2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">Drag&Drop Area</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because when you set the textContent property, any child nodes are removed and replaced by a single Text node containing the specified string. So you are replacing your dropped img with the new text/empty string.

Append the image after clearing the text.

```css
.dropdiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
}

img {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="drop0" class="dropdiv" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">Drag&Drop Area 1</div>
<div id="drop1" class="dropdiv" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">Drag&Drop Area 2</div>
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/100" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true" id="drag1" />


<script>
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
   
 if (ev.target.id == 'drop0') {
        document.getElementById('drop0').innerText = "";
    } else if (ev.target.id == 'drop1'){
        document.getElementById('drop1').innerText = "";
    }
   document.getElementById(data).style.border='none';
   ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
   
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

your code is removing the items after drop.

call the appendchild method after the if statement.

```js
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    
    if (ev.target.id == 0) {
        document.getElementById('0').textContent = '';
        document.getElementById('1').textContent = 'some text'
    } else if (ev.target.id == 1){
        document.getElementById('0').textContent = 'some other text';
        document.getElementById('1').textContent = '';
    }
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

Comment: whoa, thanks! that was easy ...but I still have a problem. the divs are bordered squares and the photo is too and should fit it but the div changes it size after drop, I guess because there is still the text but hidden. can you suggest an idea how to fix that? I tried setting the text to 0px size that it doesn't cover any space but that apparently isn't a good approach or setting the size of div inside the script but that isn't the way either.

Comment: you can remove the div borders on drop by doing something like this document.getElementById("0").style.border = "none"; borders of the picture will take its place.

Comment: but I need the borders to be there

Comment: check if there is some padding in the drop div. Request you to create a fiddle for your code. It will help in identifying the actual error.

Comment: @chaturanga Does my snippet not do this?

Comment: @Coffee bean your code is correct. Can you figure out what is causing the size issue?.

Comment: @chaturanga I don't see any size issue, you haven't posted a working snippet of the issue. use my code as an example.

Comment: @Coffee bean oh yeah, ok, your code works fine, my size issues are caused by other things set in .dropdiv. because I need to center the text within the square so I was using line-height to achieve it. need to find other way to do that but otherwise it works. thank you.

Comment: @chaturanga No problem, glad it helped :)